# caffe resize image make all values 0

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I encountered this problem when working with caffe to generate HDF5 data files from images.

the `caffe.io.load_image` loads images into a varible in the normalized range 0-1.

**resizes but all values in `img` converted to zero**

```
    img = caffe.io.load_image( patht_to_file )
    print img.shape
    print img.dtype
    img = caffe.io.resize( img, (3,SIZE, SIZE) ) #resizes but all values in img converted to zero
    print img.shape
    print img.dtype
```

the output I get is

```
  (240, 320, 3) 
  float32
  (3, 58, 58) 
  float64
```

the values of the `img` is  changed for some values to all 0's
could any one help me fix this.

I would like the same float32 changing the order of the `resize` command gives the correct output
**Gives real non zero values to var `img`**
**but order and type is not one I need**

```
img = caffe.io.resize( img, (SIZE, SIZE, 3) ) # Gives real non zero values to var img
print img.shape
print img.dtype
```

output

```
(240, 320, 3) 
float32
(58, 58, 3) 
float64
```

**I need the shape to be 3,58,58 without converting all values to zeros ie real data**

Comment: did you feel much of a difference with `img = caffe.io.resize_image( img, (SIZE,SIZE), interp_order=3 )`? Because I am doing somehow similar experiment and resizing images to network input (`data`) size does not change my results!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What went wrong?

your `img` is a 3-D array, but there is a different meaning to the different dimensions. The first two `(240,320)` are *spatial* dimensions while the third `(3)` is the "channel" (or "feature") dimension. When `resize`-ing an image you want to change the *spatial* dimensions and even mix (interpolate) neighboring values, but you always want to keep the channels intact: you do not want to mix "red" values in order to decide on "green" values for neighboring pixels.

In caffe, in order to take an input image of shape `(240,320,3)` and transform it into shape `(3,58,58)` you need to do **two** things:
 1. Change the *spatial* dimensions from `(240,320)` to `(58,58)` using `caffe.io.resize_image`. This stage will result with `img` of shape `(58,58,3)`.
 2. The second stage is to shift/`transpose` the dimensions of the `img` so that the channels dimension will be the first: `img.transpose((2,0,1))`.

#### Solution:

```
# first, resize the spatial dimensions, do not touch the channels
img = caffe.io.resize_image( img, (SIZE,SIZE), interp_order=3 )
# transpose the dimensions from H-W-C to C-H-W
img = img.transpose( (2,0,1) )
```

See [`resize_image`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py#L305) for more details.

PS,
It is also very common to change RGB image to BGR. You skipped this stage. Is that intentional?

Comment: I'm getting an error "resize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interp_order'"

Comment: yes while it really does not bring any gain in classification i just decided to skip it.
I have another question when performing HDF5 data training on which diementions are the convolutions performed ?
for eg consider this data file has 200 imgs  the HDF5 data would be of the form 200x58x58x3.
Where would the 2d convolution take place ? on the spatial 58*58 ? 
or does caffe think this image has 58 channels each of size 58*3 and perform convolutions on this 58*3 dimention ??

Comment: @ArsenalFanatic by default, caffe's convolutions act on the last two dimensions, considering the second one to be the feature dimension. If you want your caffe to function properly, feed it data with shape Batch-Channel-Height-Width.